# I have series of times in and our report like example below

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want the break duration report for this. I have my employees in and out report and how can I pull out the total break duration between the time slots?

[image: time in-out duration report]

Tried with mod formula like mod(cell1-cell2,1)+mod(cell3-cell4,1)+mod(cell5-cell6,1)+..... –

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried with mod formula like mod(cell1-cell2,1)+mod(cell3-cell4,1)+mod(cell5-cell6,1)+.....

Comment: Make your question better by adding requested information to the question itself and not in comments.

Comment: it was added, help me with this